# Auto Sort not working on Multiple Sheets within one Google Sheet

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

I want Sheet 2 (Titled "Deals in Escrow") to auto sort by date and Sheet 1 (Titled "Loan Inquiries") to auto sort by last name.  Both Sheets are within a single Google Sheet.  I have found the following script, and I modified it slightly and it works great on Sheet 2 to auto sort by date;

```
//Updates sort for range automatically
function onEdit(event){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var columnToSortBy = 7;
  var tableRange = "A3:T99"; //range to be sorted
  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange); 
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  }
}
```

However, I want the 1st Sheet to auto sort by Last Name which is in Column 2, rather than Column 7 that the script refers to.
For what it's worth, I made the following changes to the script and added in the following script which works well to sort by last name in column 2 on Sheet 1;

```
//Updates sort for range automatically
function onEdit(event){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 2;
  var tableRange = "A3:T99"; //range to be sorted

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange); 
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  }
}
```

But the problem is that by doing so, the other script to auto sort by date in Sheet 2 has now been disabled.

I've also tried creating a Name Range in each sheet and putting NamedRange1 and NameRange2 in the table range section of the script.  It hasn't changed anything.  Sheet 1 is still sorting by last name and Sheet 2 is not sorting.

```
//Updates sort for range automatically
function onEdit(event){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 2;
  var tableRange = "NamedRange1"; //range to be sorted

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange); 
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use getSheetByName for each of the functions

Comment: Is that instead of getActiveSheet?

Comment: Sorry no it comes after getActiveSheet as an additional method e.g. getActiveSheet().getSheetByName - im on an airplane lol so i can take a look once we hit wifi capable elevation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
function onEdit(event){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet().getName()
  var editedCell = event.range.getSheet().getActiveCell();
if(sheet=="Loan Inquiries"){
  var columnToSortBy = 2;
  var tableRange = "A3:T99"; //range to be sorted
  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(tableRange); 
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  }}
  else if(sheet=="Deals in Escrow"){
    var columnToSortBy = 7;
    var tableRange = "A3:T99"; //range to be sorted
  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
     var range = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(tableRange); 
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  }
  else{return}
}}
```

Test spreadsheet:

```
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13vveA0n4w84yQ71no7LgGonz_wLE7H_RA1ocDOtLZPQ/edit?usp=sharing
```

Comment: I get this error message when running that code;  TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 3, file "Sort by Last Name")

Comment: I noticed that your test spreadsheet doesn't auto sort on the date

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ok, it's working on both Sheets, but when I use your code, I get that error above

Comment: I deleted my 2nd auto sort code and changed my 1st script to yours from the the test spreadsheet.  It asked for permissions and I gave it and then I get this message;  TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 3, file "Code")

Comment: you can't run the script through the console because it needs an event to occur.  The script will automatically run when the spreadsheet is edited and the error should not occur. You can check the execution transcript to confirm this.

Comment: Ok, get this, I do get the error message above when I run it from the project page, YET, it is working!  It's auto sorting by name on the correct sheet and auto sorting by date on the 2nd sheet.  Well done.

Comment: I just saw your message above.  Ok great.  Thanks for the help.  Problem resolved!

Comment: If possible, is there a way to setup this if/then to add in yet another Sheet?  And that third sheet would be locked to many but not to me and one other person.  The Sheet name would be "Karlan Production for 2017" and would be formatted the same as "Deals in Escrow".  Finally, is there a way for anything that is typed into "Deals in Escrow" to be automatically imported, and sorted, in "Karlan Production for 2017"?

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please approve the answer and enter a new question. What you are asking can be done. A sample spreadsheet with data would be helpful to get you an answer you can use.

Comment: How do I approve the answer?

Comment: Click the checkmark under this post, on the left. (I think it's right below the arrows).

Comment: Under the arrows is a star to select to make it a favorite.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. I will have an answer to your new question soon.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `getSheetByName` method instead :

for example:

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetByName('Deals in Escrow');
```

Comment: I run that and I get the following: TypeError: Cannot find function getActiveSheet in object Sheet. (line 4, file "Sort by Last Name")