# Wanting auto sort on 3 sheets, when one is locked

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Please see the previous post on this question;
[Auto Sort not working on Multiple Sheets within one Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303706/auto-sort-not-working-on-multiple-sheets-within-one-google-sheet/41305090?noredirect=1#comment69822845_41305090)

Here's the good script from that last session;

```
function onEdit(event){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet().getName()
  var editedCell = event.range.getSheet().getActiveCell();
if(sheet=="Loan Inquiries"){
  var columnToSortBy = 2;
  var tableRange = "A3:G99"; //range to be sorted
  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(tableRange); 
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  }}
  else if(sheet=="Deals in Escrow"){
    var columnToSortBy = 7;
  var tableRange = "A3:I99"; //range to be sorted
  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
     var tableRange = "A3:I99"; //range to be sorted
     var range = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(tableRange); 
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  }
  else{return}
}}

function test_onEdit() {
  onEdit({
    user : Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
    source : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
    range : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell(),
    value : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell().getValue(),
    authMode : "LIMITED"
  });
}
```

This thread successfully resolved my question, however, now what I want to do is to Auto Sort a 3rd Sheet, which is locked to others, but not to myself.  The 3rd Sheet will be titled "Karlan Production for 2017".  I also want this 3rd sheet to pull all new data from the 2nd Sheet "Deals in Escrow" and in the same formatting as the 2nd Sheet and to auto sort as the data is imported to the 3rd Sheet, but also be able for me to input new deals manually as well in the 3rd Sheet and still be able to auto update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will do what you want:

```
function onEdit(event){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet().getName()
  var editedCell = event.range.getSheet().getActiveCell();
if(sheet=="Loan Inquiries"){
  var columnToSortBy = 2;
  var tableRange = "A3:G99"; //range to be sorted
  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(tableRange); 
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  }}
  else if(sheet=="Deals in Escrow"){
    var columnToSortBy = 7;
    var tableRange = "A3:I99"; //range to be sorted
  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(tableRange); 
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
    combineData()
  }}
   else if(sheet=="Karlan Production for 2017"){
     var columnToSortBy = 7;
     if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){ 
  combineData()
   }}
  else{return}
}

function combineData(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s=ss.getSheets()[1]
var lr = s.getLastRow()
var s1=ss.getSheets()[2]
var lr1 = s1.getLastRow()
var lc1=s1.getLastColumn() //get the last column of 'Karlan Production for 2017' 
var rng=s.getRange(3, 1, lr,lc1).getValues() //get 'Deals in Escrow' values
var rng1=s1.getRange(3, 1, lr1,lc1).getValues() //get 'Karlan Production for 2017' values
var rng2=[]
var rng2=rng.concat(rng1) //combine 'Deals in Escrow' and 'Karlan Production   for 2017' values (all rows)
removeDuplicates(rng2) // call remove duplicates sending combined array  
}

function removeDuplicates(data) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s1=ss.getSheets()[2]
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if(row.join() == newData[j].join()){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);//create array of non duplicate rows
    }
  }
  s1.clearContents(); //clear 'Karlan Production for 2017'
  var sor=s1.getRange(3, 1, newData.length,     newData[0].length).setValues(newData); //set new array
  sor.sort( { column : 7, ascending: true } );//sort new data
}
```

After adding the new sheet, click the arrow on the sheet tab.
Click Protect Sheet. In the popup, enter a description and click
the Sheet button. Click the Set permissions button. In the Range
editing permissions popup click the arrow by 'Only you'. Select 
'Custom' and add the email address of the other person you want 
to be able to edit the sheet. Click done.

Comment: You sir, are a genius.  Works perfectly.

Comment: Sorry!  I said it worked perfectly, and at first glance it did.  However, here's the problem.  The first 9 columns are identical, but the 3rd Sheet has an additional 9 columns going to R and I may add a few more later.  And when any info is entered on the 2nd sheet, it does immediately duplicate that entry onto the 3rd Sheet, but it erases all the column to the right of I.

Comment: I answered your question as asked. Please approve it. If you have more requirements ask another question. Also, show what you tried to solve your new problem. This is not a code service.

Comment: Understood.  However, this is beyond my capabilities to resolve.  I'm just a tinkerer with code.  If you can help, I'd even be willing to pay for it.

Comment: I updated the answer to handle your new requirement. Enjoy.

Comment: I have been using this for a bit and have found a glitch on the Production Page.  When I put in a row of info on the Karlan Production page it re-grabs the info from the Deals in Escrow page and makes another copy of that data in the Karlan Production page.  So when I enter a new row, I end up with duplicates of the data that was already pulled from the Deals in Escrow page.  Again, I am willing and happy to pay you for this work.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Final question, I hope, when changes are made in Deals in Escrow, they don't propagate into the Production page except as a duplicate entry as mentioned earlier.  Is there a way for changes, as they are made in the Deals in Escrow page to propagate into the Karlan Production page?  Again, I'd love to pay you and could do it via PayPal if you have an account.

Comment: SO doesn't like these conversations to get too long, which I agree with. Our time difference makes chat hard. My email id ednelson@sbcglobal.net. Send me an email and I will have your address. I think I have a fix.

Comment: Just sent you an email.  bryan@bryankarlan.com